# cucumber-js not working with node command

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumberjs

On my windows machine, on a cucumber.js project I get:

```
> success on 'cucumber-js' success on
> 'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js' success on
> 'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js.cmd' Error on : 
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\proj06_npm_run_test>node
> cucumber-js module.js:340
>     throw err;
>     ^
> 
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\proj06_npm_run_test\cucumber-js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
>     at startup (node.js:138:18)
>     at node.js:974:3
> 
> Error on:
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\proj06_npm_run_test>node
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js.cmd
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js.cmd:1 (function
> (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST
> "%~dp0\node.exe" (
>                                                               ^
> 
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
>     at startup (node.js:138:18)
>     at node.js:974:3
> 
> Error on:
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\proj06_npm_run_test>node
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js
> C:\Users\mayank.arora\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber-js:4 case `uname`
> in ^^^^
> 
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token case
>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
>     at startup (node.js:138:18)
>     at node.js:974:3
```